# Makefile target dependency to generated files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a question regarding the behavior of Make when running targets that are dependent on generated files.

Given the source tree and Makefile below, when I run this it takes two runs to complete the "build" even though everything was generated on the first run.

```
$ ls -R
.:
bar  foo  Makefile
```

### Makefile

```
all: foobar

work:
    mkdir -p work

work/foo: work foo
    cp foo work/foo

work/bar: work bar
    cp bar work/bar

foobar: work/foo work/bar
```

### make

```
$ make
mkdir -p work
cp foo work/foo
cp bar work/bar
$ ls -R
.:
work/  bar  CMakeLists.txt  foo  Makefile

./work:
bar  foo
$ make
cp foo work/foo
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: It looks as if it *does* complete the build on the first pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the directory an [*order-only*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) prerequisite, otherwise the targets will be remade each time the directory changes; during the second invocation `work` is newer than `work/foo` because `work/bar` was created after `work/foo`, so `work`'s timestamp is newer than `work/foo`.

```
work/foo: foo | work
    cp foo work/foo

work/bar: bar | work
    cp bar work/bar
```

Or more concisely

```
work/foo work/bar: work/%: % | work
    cp $< $@
```